# SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP - After adding jks file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jks

After creating a https port on `jenkins` and added a `jks` file in the `jenkins.xml` file, I'm receiving this error when I try to reach the jenkins via https (from the browser):

> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8081. Cannot
>   communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
>   Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Does anybody know why this happens?

P.S. In the JKS file exists only one crt file